# Get ID of first empty element

Tags: jquery

This function captures the ID of the first empty element when a page is submitted.

The challenge is it's always firing on my first element even if it has a value. When folks enter a value in the form elements, I want those elements skipped.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('.analytics:first').each(function() {
        var getid = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($(this).val() == '' || ($(this).not(':selected')) || ($(this).not(':checked'))) {
            alert(getid);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/meq27wse/90/

Comment: The OR condition, one of the condition will always evaluate to `true`

Comment: Why are you using `:first`?

Comment: because I want the first element that is empty

Comment: @Evan And how may elements will be there which are `first`

Comment: `.analytics:first` selects the first element that has the class of analytics. It has nothing to do with it being empty.

Comment: Ok. I understand j0, therefore its always the first one. Darn. what would you suggest?

Comment: Loop through all the elements matching the class. When you find an empty one, alert it and return `false` to end the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Javascript function to check for type and values and iterate through all elements in that class.

http://jsfiddle.net/meq27wse/95/

```
$('#submit').live('click',function(){


$('.analytics').each(function(){

  var getid = $(this).attr('id');
    if($(this).is('input') && $(this).val()=='')
    {
         alert(getid + $(this).val());
        return false;
    }
    else if($(this).is('select') && $(this).val()==="")
    {
         alert(getid);
        return false;
    }
    else if($(this).is(':checkbox') && !$(this).checked)
    {
         alert(getid);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
      //all OK
    }
 /* if($(this).val() == '' || ($(this).not(':selected')) || ($(this).not(':checked'))) {
     alert(getid);
  }*/

});

    });
```

Comment: That does the trick however, checkbox is not working properly. It seems to always alert even if they are checked?

Comment: @Evan Slightly updated logic    else if($(this).is(':checkbox'))
    {
        var count_checked = $("[name='newsletter']:checked").length;
        if(count_checked == 0) 
        {
       alert(getid);
         return false;
        }
    }   http://jsfiddle.net/meq27wse/101/

Comment: I added a little flair to your logic http://jsfiddle.net/meq27wse/102/ with the radio buttons and checkboxes. That seem to clean that up nicely. Just have to step through the whole form the submit each one to view the alerts.